# Ruby Programming: Predicate Methods

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and came across the `defined?` operator. I thought the `?` implied that the method returned `true`/`false` but `defined?` returns a description of the identifier if it is defined.

I know that there is a `true`/`false` component in that the identifier is or is not defined but I thought that the `?` meant that the return value always had to be `true`/false`. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns a "truthy" value that is either "truthy-true" or "truthy-false".

In Ruby, there are *only* two things that are truthy-false:

- `false` (the singleton object)
- `nil` (the singleton object)

*Anything* else is considered truthy-true. Tons of Ruby code leverages this fact for predicates. Checks for predicates, as such, should be:

```
if list.empty?
```

not:

```
if list.empty? == true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
defined? a    #=> nil
a = 7         # => 7 
defined? a    #=> "local-variable"
```

While it does not pass back actual 'true' or 'false' values it still functions in the same way.

```
if defined? a  
  puts "This will still act as true"
end
  #=> This will still act as true
```

The reason for this is because in ruby EVERYTHING is true with the exception of `false` and `nil`.

This [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#definedandorandnot) has a lot more information on the `defined?` operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a convention and not part of the language, so there is no actual rule surrounding question marks.  From http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/

"By convention, methods that answer questions (i.e. Array#empty? returns true if the receiver is empty) end in question marks."

Answer (score 0):

"non-nil"/nil is the same as true/false in Ruby. If you come from other language, you might have this habit of testing using true/false, but in Ruby we test if an object is nil or not.

so these two are the same:

```
a = 'hello'
if defined?(a) then puts a end

a = 'hello'
if defined?(a) != nil then puts a end
```

If you insist you want to return true/false, you can use the second one. This will return true/false:

```
a != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The `defined?` operator returns `nil` if its argument (which can be an arbitrary expression) is not defined, otherwise it returns a description of that argument.

And since `nil` evaluates to false and (except for false) all other expressions evaluate to true, the behaviour of `defined?` is as one expects.